# Split a Column of json Object to More Column via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, object

How Can I Split This json Object to 3 Part `id` `awnser` and `type` ?

```
[{"id":"26","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"a"},
 {"id":"30","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"b"},
 {"id":"31","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"c"}]
```

And db Name: `array` Table Name: `user_survey_start` JSON Column Name: `survey_answers`, This is my code:

```
        <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
 $sql="SELECT `survey_answers` FROM `user_survey_start`";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: split to 3 json objects ? `{"id":"26"}`  `{"answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}]}`    `{"type":"a"}`

Comment: Can I have Something like This?  `26,30,31`  and `High,low.low`   and `a,b,c`   //This is one Row after That next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `json_decode()`

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT  `survey_answers` FROM `user_survey_start`";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
 {

    $json = $row[0];
    $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach ($jason_array as $data){
        $id[] = $data['id'];
        $answer[] = $data['answer'];
        $type[] = $data['type'];

        // here code to insert/update values to db column
    }

    echo implode(',',$id);
    echo implode(',',$answer);
    echo implode(',',$type);
  }

}
```

Comment: I need a Code to Read **phpMyAdmin jsons Column**.....I Mean This is a Row of My rows

Comment: don't you get the data using your query `$sql="SELECT  survey_answers FROM user_survey_start";` ?? @SedricHeidarizarei

Comment: I'm New in Programming, Can you write me a Correct Code With my Db Name and Db Table? `$json = all Row of my Column`

Comment: What Should I Tell You? I Attached a Photo in my Question, json Object is Awnsers of our questions, and i need a Report or log

Comment: How Can I  printf My Rows Like This Format: `26,30,31` and `High,low.low` and `a,b,c` , Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135755/discussion-between-mith-and-sedric-heidarizarei).

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php on line 19

Comment: I Edited my Question